Parsing an array with specific amount of elements
I've recently tried to parse an array with a fixed size in antlr4:
array[int size]
    : {size > 0}? thing array[$size - 1]
    | 
    ;

This allows me to have arrays with a size determined by my data, e.g.
foo: number array[$number.value]; // array with $number amount of elements

My problem is that this approach has massive overhead (stack overflow for big arrays).
Is there a good way to linearize this approach?
I've tried to "optimize" it: (TARGET: Java)
array[int length] returns [ThingContext[] objects]:
        {
            _localctx.objects = new ThingContext[length];
        }
        ( {$length > 0}?
         firstObject=thing {
            _localctx.objects[0] = _localctx.firstObject;
            for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
                _localctx.objects[i] = thing();
            }
        }
        |
        );

This seems to mess with the adaptive prediction, though (I'm sometimes getting an infinite loop).
Any ideas?

What you posted does not seem to be valid ANTLR syntax. I cannot verify that without you posting a MCVE.
But this works:
grammar Array;

parse
 : ( declaration {System.out.printf("values: %s%n", $declaration.values);} )+ EOF
 ;

declaration returns [List<Integer> values]
 : number array[$number.value] {$values = $array.values;}
 ;

array[int length] returns [List<Integer> values]
@init {
  $values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
 : ( {$values.size() < $length}? number {$values.add($number.value);} )+
 ;

number returns [int value]
 : INT {$value = Integer.parseInt($INT.text);}
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\f\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

When parsing the input:
3 1 2 3        1 4        2 5 6

the following parse tree is created:
'- parse
   |- declaration
   |  |- number
   |  |  '- '3' (INT)
   |  '- array
   |     |- number
   |     |  '- '1' (INT)
   |     |- number
   |     |  '- '2' (INT)
   |     '- number
   |        '- '3' (INT)
   |- declaration
   |  |- number
   |  |  '- '1' (INT)
   |  '- array
   |     '- number
   |        '- '4' (INT)
   |- declaration
   |  |- number
   |  |  '- '2' (INT)
   |  '- array
   |     |- number
   |     |  '- '5' (INT)
   |     '- number
   |        '- '6' (INT)
   '- '<EOF>'

And when invoking the parse rule, this is also printed to your console:
values: [1, 2, 3]
values: [4]
values: [5, 6]

I should also add that it is not best practice to embed so much target specific code inside the grammar: it makes for hard to maintain code, and the grammar is much harder to port to some other target. I do realize that the way you allow arrays to be created (N 1, 2, ..., N) makes it necessary for some target specific code.
